# How to tell if the key is down or up

Tags: python, keyboard

This current code runs if the key is down, but I only want it to run if the key is up otherwise it will spam the code and I don't want that to happen, does anyone know how to do this?

```
import keyboard

if keyboard.is_pressed('f') and keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
    print("clicked")
```

Comment: `if not(keyboard.is_pressed('f') and keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'))` ?

Comment: No I want the script undeath to run if the f + ctrl key is up

Comment: So, then, it will run if you use my above `if` statement. If that doesn't help you then you're not being clear enough as to what you need. You need to show some clear examples of what you really need and you should explain in detail how my code does not help, since I believe it actually should help.